# Removing trailing spaces with the substitute command changes the cursor position

Tags: cursor-movement, substitute, whitespace

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces

```
function TrimWhiteSpace()
  %s/\s\+$//e
endfunction

autocmd FileWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd FileAppendPre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd FilterWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
autocmd BufWritePre * call TrimWhiteSpace()
```

On `:write` the cursor moves to the first non-blank character of the last trimmed line. How can I make it stay in place?

Answer (score 4):

Save the position and restore it again, as in:

```
function TrimWhiteSpace()
  let save_cursor = getcurpos()
  %s/\s\+$//e
  call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction
```